# Getting position fixed elements using JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a free hosting and the server creating some ads on page. I want to hide them with a js but they don't have a class or id. I have an idea but don't know it is possible or not.

The ads has `position: fixed` attribute and i don't have an element styled as `fixed`. So if I can hide fixed elements by use of JS, it solves my problem.

In this case I need some help on how to find `position:fixed` elements through JS. Thanks.

Comment: Don't violate their terms.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for notice. there is no violation because it's their advice: `<!--SCRIPT GENERATED BY SERVER! PLEASE REMOVE-->`. also I will use host only 1 day for my school project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
  $('*').filter(function() {
        if($(this).css("position") === 'fixed'){
              $(this).hide();
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will hide all elements with `position : fixed`

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("position") === "fixed";
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it's really nasty :)

You have to search for elements that have a position:fixed, like that (with jQuery, I'm lazy):

```
$('body *').each(function() {
  if($(this).css('position') == 'fixed'){
    // Hide it the way you want (i.e. : $(this).css('display', 'none'); :)
  }
});
```

That will do the job, but that's not really clean.